# Limit substitution domain restriction

Tags: limits, substitution

I apologize in advance for the imprecise question but I don't really know what I am looking for here.
In doing classwork I have come across various limits where the obvious substitution would be $t=x^2$.

For example, in the case of the limit
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\cos(x))^{-\frac{4}{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^{-\frac{4}{x^2}}$$
I would substitute $t=-\frac{2}{x^2}$ which would however imply that $x=\pm \sqrt{-\frac{2}{t}}$

This does lead to the correct result, $e^2$, but it feels like this would restrict the domain of $t$ to $(-\infty;0]$ so the answer feels incomplete or as though it would need some extra consideration. I would appreciate any pointers to what could be a more complete or formally correct solution. Thank you.

Comment: If u want to have a complete solution you can take y equal to your limit then apply log both sides then apply l hopital's rule which will yeild the result ln y = 2 which gives y=e^2